# How to provide ssh_username when using packer to build a windows AMI

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, packer

When I run `packer build -var aws_access_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -var aws_secret_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY windows-2012.json`

I got this error:

```
1 error(s) occurred:

* An ssh_username must be specified
  Note: some builders used to default ssh_username to "root".
```

However there is no native support of ssh in windows 2012. So how can I come up with a `ssh_username`?

When I was using terraform to build the server, I used `WinRM` protocol. Can I instruct packer to use WinRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem goes away when I switched to use `WinRM`